# Mixpanel: people analytics without signing in

Tags: javascript, analytics, mixpanel

Since I don't have a back-end, I was wondering if there was a way to get people analytics in Mixpanel without having to sign them in.
Or if there is any other way without an API...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution using localStorage:

```
if (localStorage.userID!== undefined) {
    mixpanel.identify(localStorage.userID);
    mixpanel.people.set({
        $last_login: moment().format()
    });
} else {
    var id = moment().format();

    localStorage.userID = id;
    mixpanel.identify(id);
    mixpanel.people.set({
        $created: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
        $last_login: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
        next_clicks: 0
    });
}
```

This works perfectly fine, with users registered with the date (including seconds) they first connected.
I hope it will help someone!